# Is there a way to call a typescript function from javascript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a "get" function in a typescript file and I need to use this function in a different javascript file. Is there a way to achieve it?

I have tried to write "static" and "public" in front of the function name but it didn't work.

Comment: Typescript is just a wrapper. It will be transpiled into JS. So you call it like a normal JS function.

Comment: Could you post code and maybe write out why you want to do this? There may be a better way to solve the problem. Otherwise you should be able to explicitly add it to the window object `(window as any).get = get`.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a HostListener

Component code:

```
  @HostListener('window:yourFunction', ['$event','$event.detail.type'])
  yourInternalFunction(event,param) {
    //do something
  }
```

On js file

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('yourFunction', {detail:{type:1}}));
```

Comment: The op wants to call typescript from JavaScript and get the value back, as it's a getter. Your code does not show how to get the return value back